# Get SCOPE_IDENTITY value when inserting bulk records for SQL TableType

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, scope-identity

I have following table structure, for convenience purpose I am only marking individual columns

- `Table_A` (`Id, Name, Desc`)
- `Table_1` (`Id` *this is identity column*, `Name`....)
- `Table_2` (`Id` *this is identity column*, `Table_A_Id`, `Table_1_Id`)

The relationship between Table_1 and Table_2 is `1...*`

Now I have created a table type for `Table_A` called `TType_Table_A` (which only contains `Id` as column and from my C# app I send multiple records). I have achieved this bulk insert functionality as desired.

What I need is when I insert records into `Table_2` from `TType_Table_A` say with below statements, I would like to capture the `Id` of `Table_2` for each record inserted

```
declare @count int = (select count(*) from @TType_Table_A); --a variable declared for TType_Table_A

if(@count > 0)
  begin
    insert into Table_2(Table_A_Id,Table_1_Id)
    SELECT @SomeValue, @SomeValueAsParameter FROM @TType_Table_A;
  end;
```

Now say if 2 records are inserted, I would like to capture the `Id` for each of these 2 records.

Any input/help is appreciated

This is what I know how it can be achieved, but I want to reduce DB calls from my app or user cursor in stored procedure

Insert record in Table_1 and return back the Id Loop.....through records and insert record in Table_2 and return back the Id

OR

Use cursor in stored procedure when inserting/selecting from TableType

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume this is Sql Server?  Then you can make use of the OUTPUT clause, like so:

```
declare @NewId table (MyNewId INT) 

 insert into Table_2(Table_A_Id,Table_1_Id)
 output INSERTED.MyNewId INTO @TempTable(MyNewID)
 SELECT SomeValue, SomeValueAsParameter FROM @TType_Table_A;

 SELECT * FROM @NewId
```